# How to setup server side rendering with react-router 2

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, reactjs, react-router

I want to port my app to react-router 2.0 from 1.0. I am trying to do server side rendering on express.

### server.js code (1.0) (working)

```
var routes = require('./public/js/app.node.js');

app.get('*', function(req, res, next) {

  var location = new Location(req.path, req.query);

  try {
    Router.run(routes(), location, function(e, i, t) {
      var str = React.renderToString(
                  React.createElement(Router, i));
    });
  } catch(e) {
    return next();
  }
});
```

### server.js code (2.0) (Not working)

```
var routes = require('./public/js/app.node.js');

app.get('*', function(req, res, next) {

  var location = new Location(req.path, req.query);

  try {
  match({routes, location: req.url} , function (error, redirectLocation, renderProps) {
      if (error) {
        res.status(500).send(error.message);
      } else if (redirectLocation) {
        res.redirect(302, redirectLocation.pathname + redirectLocation.search);
      } else if (renderProps) {
        var str = renderToString(React.createElement(RoutingContext, renderProps));
        res.status(200).send(str);
      } else {
        res.status(404).send('Not found');
      }
  });
}
```

### routes.jsx:

```
  export default (withHistory, onUpdate) => {

  return (
    <Provider store={store}>
      <Router history={history} onUpdate={onUpdate}>
        <Route path='/' component={BarcodeListing} />
      </Router>
    </Provider>
  );
};
```

The above code does not match `/`. Why is that. 
`console.log(req.url)` gives me `/`, then `/` in routes should match `/` in req.url right !!

Comment: You've updated the history module to `2.0.0-rc2` too right? I recommend you pass `browserHistory` from `react-router`. Like this - https://github.com/DominicTobias/universal-react/blob/master/app/Router.js